# How to sort a list in Python3 where no cmp operator is defined with the elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, topological-sort

How to sort a list in Python3 where no cmp operator is defined with the elements?

I would like to sort a list in which the elements are *comparable* to each other with a certain rule but where no explicit simple comparison operators (eg, `<` and `>`) are defined for them.  Take this example set of dictionaries and its collection (list):

```
dNik = { 'id': 'Nik', 'parent': 'Ann' }
dAnn = { 'id': 'Ann', 'parent': ''    }
dBob = { 'id': 'Bob', 'parent': 'Nik' }
arry = [ dNik, dAnn,  dBob ]
```

The relative relation of these dictionaries can be worked out; basically,

```
Bob (child) < Nik (parent) < Ann (grandparent)
```

(**EDIT** -- Here `dBob` knows nothing about `dAnn` and `dAnn` knows nothing about the others --)
So now, I would like to sort the list `arry` with shuffled elements of these in this order of the child-parent relation;

```
arry = [ dNik, dAnn, dBob ]
sorted(arry, key=lambda i: SOMETHING)
  # => [ dBob, dNik, dAnn ]
```

What's the (best) way to achieve this?
(**EDIT** -- the algorithm does not have to use the built-in `sorted()`, but anything that achieves the purpose is fine! --)

**Note**: In this simple rule, a dictionary may potentionally have multiple children dictionaries. In such a case, let's say, the relation between those children hashes are undefined (or you can introduce another rule, such as the alphabetical order with the name). Either way.

**[EDIT]**:
As pointed out in comments and an answer, this is a problem of [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and is impossible to implement with built-in `sort()` or `sorted()` in Python (3.8). Now, to clarify, my question is simply "how to achieve the sorting as described in the example"?
I note that *pip*-installable basic Python module [toposort](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/) is available for it (which is implemented built-in in forthcoming Python-3.9 as [functools.TopologicalSorter()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.TopologicalSorter). It seems to be useful, though the case in this question requires a bit of work to apply it to.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "topological sort". You will not be able to use `sorted` for this.

Comment: I see! The [toposort](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/) library may do the job, then. I'll look for it. Thanks @Sneftel

Answer (score 0):

If only the comparison is the problem you can specify your own:

```
sorted(arry, 
       cmp=lambda x, y: x-y # insert custom logic here
      )
```

That said the sorting algorithms expect a fully ordered set of entries. That is `cmp(dBob, dAnn)` should return -1, because Bob is Ann grandson. Not sure if you can get that from what you mentioned in the question.

Like @Sneftel mentioned, it looks like what you are actually looking for is a topological sort. Fortunately, there is a `toposort` package you can install and will provide the algorithm for it, but you will need to provide your data in the right format (dictionary of element to it's children).

Comment: If you're still advocating Python 2, you might as well advocate Python 3.9 and its topological sort.

Comment: The question is explicitly for Python 3. But this answer is for Python 2 (as @HeapOverflow has rightly pointed out); `sorted()` in Python 3 does not take the option `cmp` but `key` and does not accept 2 parameters for the `lambda`. But thanks you for pointing out the `toposort` package (which I didn't know)! That seems to provide a solution (I will look for it). Indeed, I have confirmed it is planned to be available built-in in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

As commented (and reflected in the edited question), this type of sorting, called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), cannot be achieved with Python built-in `sort`.  Instead, it can be done with the *pip*-installable library [toposearch](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/), which will be available as built-in in the next Python-3.9.

Here is an answer to the question by using the toposearch library:

```
from toposort import toposort_flatten

lst_sorted = toposort_flatten({i['id']:{i['parent']} for i in arry})
  # => ['', 'Ann', 'Nik', 'Bob']
lst_rev    = list(reversed(lst_sorted[1:]))
  # => ['Bob', 'Nik', 'Ann']
[next(x for x in arry if x['id']==j) for j in lst_rev]
  # => [{'id': 'Bob', 'parent': 'Nik'},
  #     {'id': 'Nik', 'parent': 'Ann'},
  #     {'id': 'Ann', 'parent': ''}]
```

**Description:**
Both the two functions in toposort libraries require to be fed with a simple object with the type `Dict[Any, Set[Any]]`.  In the code snippet above, a simple conversion is made from `arry` (as of the question) to a dictionary of the type to feed to `toposort_flatten`.  Finally, it is converted back to a (toposorted) list of a set of the original dictionaries.